# Eclipse Visual Editor had a very kill feature:Run As -> Java Bean, is there any other plugins can do the same?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, visual-editor

This feature can simply run a JPanel class as a application without any main funcion.

But the Visual Editor is no longer supported by new versions of Eclipse.

Do some people know other plugins can do the same?

Answer (score 0):

WindowBuilder allows you to "quickly test/preview the window without compiling or running it". The corresponding button is available when using design mode.
This way you can run a JPanel, WindowBuilder will wrap it in a JFrame for you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and sorry for the delay of reply. I do know the "quickly test/perview" can show the "layout" of my panel, BUT this JFrame wraped JPanel can not be "touched"! I click a JButton, it did not trigger the actionlistener! The displayed Components are just it's "shell", have no "core" inside...

Comment: Is there any plugins can really run a JPanel just as a mini Application? Without the main function and respond to the actions.